# How to secure Application programming model in CF

Tags: java, s4sdk

After I've done the deep dive 12
[Deep Dive 12](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/05/deep-dive-9-use-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-in-the-application-programming-model-for-sap-cloud-platform/), I've tried to secure the app with instructions from Step 7 in the series [Step 7 with SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK: Secure your Application on SAP Cloud Platform, CloudFoundry](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/).

I'm interested in getting user, so I modified the query service

```
    @Query(serviceName = "CrudService", entity = "BusinessPartner")
    public QueryResponse queryCustomers(QueryRequest qryRequest) {
       final User currentUser = UserAccessor.getCurrentUser();
       System.out.println("User: " + currentUser);

       List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners = new BusinessPartnerReadCommand(new ErpConfigContext(),
            qryRequest.getTopOptionValue(), qryRequest.getSkipOptionValue(), qryRequest.getSelectProperties(),
            qryRequest.getOrderByProperties()).execute();

        QueryResponse queryResponse = QueryResponse.setSuccess().setData(businessPartners).response();
    return queryResponse;
}
```

However, after I login via approuter, enter my credentials and it shows me the error Failed to get current user: user not authenticated.

Why it doesn't allow me to get the UserAccessor.getCurrentUser() though I login approuter?

Here is my github link: [Deep dive git](http://github.com/equilibrium999/deepdive9.git)

UPDATE: Log added

```
2018-08-20T05:44:29.139+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > approuter@1.0.0 start /home/vcap/app
2018-08-20T05:44:29.140+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > node node_modules/@sap/approuter/approuter.js
2018-08-20T05:44:29.497+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 20 05:44:29:494#+00:00#WARNING#/LoggingLibrary################PLAIN##Dynamic log level switching not available#
2018-08-20T05:44:29.756+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 20 05:44:29:756#+00:00#INFO#/approuter################PLAIN##Application router version 5.6.3#
2018-08-20T05:44:29.772+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 20 05:44:29:772#+00:00#INFO#/Configuration################PLAIN##xs-app.json: Application does not have directory for static resources!#
2018-08-20T05:44:29.792+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 20 05:44:29:792#+00:00#ERROR#/token-utils################PLAIN##can't get access token to html5 applications repository runtime service :
2018-08-20T05:44:29.792+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  [Error: html5-repo-credentials: Invalid type: null (expected object)]#
2018-08-20T05:44:29.803+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 20 05:44:29:803#+00:00#INFO#/approuter################PLAIN##Application router is listening on port: 8080#
2018-08-20T05:44:30.713+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Container became healthy
2018-08-20T05:52:34.552+0000 [RTR/6] OUT <S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-20T05:52:34.544+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 0 "https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/cockpit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.73.48:61203" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"4b864872-f2e8-408f-7acf-76807660a4c9" response_time:0.007873407 app_id:"c994cd7b-bc35-4459-b72e-49e5eb9ec849" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"be36659af8148316" x_b3_spanid:"be36659af8148316" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

2018-08-20T05:52:34.806+0000 [RTR/7] OUT <S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-20T05:52:34.791+0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 0 667 "https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/cockpit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.73.48:61203" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"ab9fd18e-ee18-4a32-7246-21b2d2328b17" response_time:0.01440516 app_id:"c994cd7b-bc35-4459-b72e-49e5eb9ec849" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"217f9f15ac4efb02" x_b3_spanid:"217f9f15ac4efb02" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

2018-08-20T05:52:34.810+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT #2.0#2018 08 20 05:52:34:809#+00:00#INFO#/Auth/OAuth2#########iIr1URai6N8Fuw2lXip84QQsHwL2At3p######ab9fd18e-ee18-4a32-7246-21b2d2328b17#PLAIN##sending page with client-side redirect to https://<S-userID>trial.authentication.us10.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb-srv-trial!t1085&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F<S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback#
2018-08-20T05:52:36.394+0000 [RTR/0] OUT <S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-20T05:52:36.129+0000] "GET /login/callback?code=tVzjsTi4Dx HTTP/1.1" 302 0 0 "https://<S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.73.48:61203" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"ee3b4a5a-e516-449d-6c2d-19a6b0807290" response_time:0.264528818 app_id:"c994cd7b-bc35-4459-b72e-49e5eb9ec849" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"3bdde9c593640d7a" x_b3_spanid:"3bdde9c593640d7a" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

2018-08-20T05:52:37.241+0000 [RTR/5] OUT <S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-20T05:52:36.630+0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 0 130 "https://<S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.73.48:61203" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"abf37d40-60a4-4e2b-401c-6681496dde90" response_time:0.610696859 app_id:"c994cd7b-bc35-4459-b72e-49e5eb9ec849" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"c263e6426f743085" x_b3_spanid:"c263e6426f743085" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

2018-08-20T05:52:37.628+0000 [RTR/5] OUT <S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-20T05:52:37.581+0000] "GET /odata/v2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 272 "https://<S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.73.48:61203" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"4f25431d-6dcb-428c-632c-f6c3b552735e" response_time:0.046654482 app_id:"c994cd7b-bc35-4459-b72e-49e5eb9ec849" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"7910f69eb99867d5" x_b3_spanid:"7910f69eb99867d5" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

2018-08-20T05:52:39.796+0000 [RTR/4] OUT <S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-20T05:52:39.461+0000] "GET /odata/v2/CrudService HTTP/1.1" 200 0 382 "https://<S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/odata/v2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.73.48:61203" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"1597c70b-ba9f-4f51-50c9-6a1824357a96" response_time:0.33434942 app_id:"c994cd7b-bc35-4459-b72e-49e5eb9ec849" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"6446d121365bf3e3" x_b3_spanid:"6446d121365bf3e3" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

2018-08-20T05:52:46.325+0000 [RTR/7] OUT <S-userID>trial-trial-dev-approuter.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com - [2018-08-20T05:52:46.196+0000] "GET /odata/v2/CrudService/BusinessPartner?$top=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 0 690 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-" "10.0.73.48:61203" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"6f2914a8-165e-4ca8-7a02-5c00ed07e7c8" response_time:0.129068343 app_id:"c994cd7b-bc35-4459-b72e-49e5eb9ec849" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"723916a7a592ec08" x_b3_spanid:"723916a7a592ec08" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
```

UPDATE: Add Java application log

[Java Log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NP3RasDyJ0zgLp8VaXDJpwj5jUifSGUB)

UPDATE: Add dependency tree file
[Dependency Tree file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GEuxsLpLJ6p5e8MsVsk_fAI59N1I0bW4)

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I use S/4HANA Cloud SDK 2.1.2

Comment: Can you also please provide a stacktrace?

Comment: I've added the log.

Comment: Could you also please provide the log files of the Java application?

Comment: The log file is added.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using version 2.1.2? From the stack trace it looks like a different version. Can you maybe share your dependency tree (`mvn dependency:tree`)?

Comment: I've added the dependency tree file.

Comment: Looking into your dependency tree and into your project I see, that you are using version 1.10.0 of the S/4HANA Cloud SDK. Your import of version 2.1.2 is not quite working. To fix this you have two options. 1) Update the `com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.prov:projects-parent-odatav2` (your projects parent) to version 1.20.1. 2) Restructure the project to use the BOM (bill of material) of the S/4HANA Cloud SDK. From version 2.3.1 on this BOM also contains the provisioning dependencies of the Cloud Platform SDK for service development, see the third step of our blog series.

Comment: I've updated it 1.20.1 and and added BOM 2.1.2 to dependency. Now it's working.

Comment: Hi Tri, can you pls provide your latest comment (above) as an answer and mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated it 1.20.1 and and added BOM 2.1.2 to dependency. Now it's working.